# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity without OWIN

Tags: asp.net-identity

We want to work with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity in order to provide Custom Claims based authentication. So far we have created our own Models (IUserStype, IUserStore ...) and our own authentication methods. So actually a User can call a login service and use the UserStore and all the functionality provided by this component.

I got stuck in how to configure an ASP.NET MVC application to use ASP.NET Identity because the only samples available on MSDN shows OWIN configuration but my app cannot be self-hosted by owin.
So should I configure this claims authentication using web.config? Any sample available online?

Comment: Did you find any link for this answer.

Comment: Yes plenty of links and projects that shows how to implement a Custom OWIN Identity Provider. The best one is this
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3

Answer (score 5):

From ASP.NET Site ,,,

> "ASP.NET authentication is now based on OWIN middleware that can be
>   used on any OWIN-based host. ASP.NET Identity does not have any
>   dependency on System.Web. It is a fully compliant OWIN framework and
>   can be used in any OWIN hosted application. ASP.NET Identity uses OWIN
>   Authentication for log-in/log-out of users in the web site. This means
>   that instead of using FormsAuthentication to generate the cookie, the
>   application uses OWIN CookieAuthentication to do that."

So you cannot use ASP.NET Identity without Owin, also, your app should not be self-hosted you can still use the IIS with OWIN configured, i suggest to dig deeper into the ASP.NET [OWIN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826757/Understanding-OWIN-and-Katana)

Comment: Update : Actually you can use the ASP.NET Identity without OWIN, but in that case you have to use the Forms Authentication classes to deal with user sign in/ sign out and cookie maintenance. but this is not useful, the combination between OWIN SignInManager and AuthenticationManager with  ASP.NET Identity is the Ultimate goal.